# how to create a request with FiddlerScript

Tags: fiddler

I want to launch fiddler from the command line and populate the request builder with given request parameters.

Is this possible using `ExecAction` (or otherwise) and `FiddlerScript`?

Can someone get me started with the necessary `FiddlerScript` needed? I can't find anything in the docs...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

FiddlerScript can generate any HTTP request you want. Look at http://fiddlerbook.com/Fiddler/dev/ScriptSamples.asp and particularly the use of the `utilIssueRequest` method.

Sending a new request to the Composer requires that you call `FiddlerApplication.DoComposeByCloning(oS)`, passing the Session to display in the Composer as the parameter.